# CSS Bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I have a problem with stylize buttons in bootstrap.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-midd">Link</button>
    <button class="btn btn-midd dropdown-toggle">
       <span class="icon-download-alt icon-gray"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to change "icon-gray" to "icon-blue". Of course i have different image (and class which change backround-image).  Icon-blue should be change on hover.

Thanks for help.

CSS:

```
.icon-blue {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-blue.png");}
 .icon-download-alt {background-position: -408px -96px;}
```

Here an example :

[image]

Comment: I confess I did not understand your question... could you clarify it a little bit?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/18975666.png/ now i have effect like in point 1). I need to add hover (onMouseOver effect) to image and change it (point 2)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.icon-download-alt:hover {background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-blue.png");}
.icon-download-alt {background-position: -408px -96px;}
```

Comment: is it possible to connect hover effect (icon-download-alt:hover) to this element <button class="btn btn-midd dropdown-toggle">? it will be better when image change onMouseOver this button class

Comment: If you want an element to change when a different element is hovered, you'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) easily employing the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("span.icon-gray").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("icon-gray");
            $(this).addClass("icon-blue");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("icon-blue");
            $(this).addClass("icon-gray");
        }
    );

});

</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately i can only use html with css

Answer (score 1):

Just put the hover on the first element. You don't want to have to hover exactly on the icon:

```
    .btn:hover .icon-download-alt { background: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-blue.png") -432px -144px; }
```

CSS, no JS required.